# Awesome WM 4.0: Layouts glitch

Tags: awesome-wm

I'm having glitching layouts in awesome wm i'm just a beginner with awesome, so don't know if this is a bug or totally my fault (probably the latter). This happens both when using the key-combinations as the buttons.

A screenshot of what happens:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kt4aH.png)

you can browse through my complete awesome config here: https://github.com/JasperDeMoor/myawesometheme

PS. I use lain by copycat-killer for cpu,ram,... widgets also i based my personal theme of of his theme multicolor the bug might be in there as well.

Kind regards and thanks in advance,
Jasper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is many possible causes

#### There is no client and no wallpaper.

When there is no client and no wallpaper, it got glitchy. This is fixed in git-master, but not in 4.0

#### There is a thin line under terminals

This is done on purpose to keep the terminal size a multiple of the character height. This can be disabled by changing the honor size hints default. See the FAQ

#### There is real glitches

Wither start a compositor such as `comton` or start awesome with `--no-argb`. Some buggy video drivers and hardware combination are known to cause this. Either solutions should work.